# Python: How to join two dataframes, where one has duplicated keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to join two dataframes, one has Id's and phone numbers, another one has bunch of other columns along with same Id field (however there are some duplicate Id's in this DF). How can I join the phone number column from first dataframe to the second one? I tried doing this but I am getting duplicated key error:

`df= df.join(other.set_index('Id'), on='Id', how='outer')`

How can I accomplish this? (I want duplicate ID's in second DF to have same phone numbers as non-duplicate ones)

Comment: Use `merge` instead of `join`, since you cannot have duplicates in your index, thus `set_index('Id')`, will throw an error.

Comment: @Erfan, I see. Could you write down approximate syntax? I tried join earlier but it didnt work for some reason, I think I might have written the code for merge incorrectly.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) an extensive read on how to merge in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with `pandas.merge` method, you can read the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
df= df.merge(other.set_index('Id'), suffixes = ('_l', '_r'), how='outer')
```

This will merge two dataframes and add suffixes for exact matching column names.